# Angular PrimeNG - Filter table with custom dropdown from array

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am trying to implement a custom filter using p-multiselect in the table header of my Angular application. However, I am facing an issue where the filter does not work on the table. Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<th style="min-width:15rem">
  <div class="flex align-items-center">
    Agent
    <p-columnFilter
      field="representative"
      matchMode="in"
      display="menu"
      [showMatchModes]="false"
      [showOperator]="false"
      [showAddButton]="false"
    >
      <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <div class="px-3 pt-3 pb-0">
          <span class="font-bold">Agent Picker</span>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
        <p-multiSelect
          [ngModel]="value"
          [options]="representatives"
          placeholder="Any"
          (onChange)="customFilter($event, dt)"
        >
          <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
            <div class="inline-block vertical-align-middle">
              <span class="ml-1 mt-1">{{ option }}</span>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
        </p-multiSelect>
      </ng-template>
    </p-columnFilter>
  </div>
</th>
```

**Component.ts**

```
customFilter(event: any, dt: any) {
  let filterBy = event.value;
  dt.filter(filterBy, 'agentName', "in");
}
```

**API Response**

```
this.representatives = ['John', 'Lina', 'Wong', 'Dev'];
```